# Tengo un pequeño problema para mi pagina web con las sesiones por inactividad

Tags: php, mysql, sesiones

Tengo este código que hace la función de un inicio de sesión, pero no consigo que me haga el cierre de sesión por inactividad, se que son 30 segundos, es para comprobar que funciona.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Aquí el código:

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "SECRET", "SECRET", "SECRET") or die("No se puede conectar con el servidor");
            
    $correo = $_REQUEST["correo"];
    $pass = $_REQUEST["pass"];
    $passencryp = md5($pass);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correo='$correo' AND contraseña='$passencryp'";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("Fallo en la consulta");
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
if (mysqli_num_rows($consulta) == 1) 
    {
        #if ($resultado['verificado'] == 0) 
        #{
        #    echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
        #          alert('¡¡¡Debe verificar su correo electrónico antes de iniciar sesión!!!');
        #          window.location.replace('./inicio_sesión.php');
        #          </script>";
        #    exit;
        #}
        
        $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $resultado['tipo_usuario'];
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado['usuario'];
        $_SESSION['contraseña'] = $resultado['contraseña'];

        if ($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == "admintech644394412")
        {
            echo "<script>window.location.replace('./admin/adminindex.php')</script>";
        }
        elseif ($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == "profesor")
        {
            echo "<script>window.location.replace('./profesor/profesorindex.php')</script>";
        }
        elseif ($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == "alumno")
        {
            echo "<script>window.location.replace('./alumno/alumnoindex.php')</script>";
        }
        elseif ($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == "padre")
        {
            echo "<script>window.location.replace('./padre/padreindex.php')</script>";
        }
        elseif ((time() - $_SESSION['time']) > 30)
        {
            header('location: ./cerrar_sesión.php');
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
                  alert('¡¡¡Uy, algo falla, compruebe los parámetros!!!');
                  window.location.replace('./inicio_sesión.php');
                  </script>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
              alert('¡¡¡Uy, algo falla, compruebe los parámetros!!!');
              window.location.replace('./inicio_sesión.php');
              </script>";
    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Primero creo la sesión, después comprueba los datos en la BBDD
, según que tipo_usuario sea le redirige a un index distinto, y añado un elseif con el cierre de sesión.

He probado otras formas y con echos o alerts y si coge el tiempo, es decir muestra cuando incia sesión, etc, pero las distintas funciones no responden, como esta:

```
        // Define el tiempo de inactividad en segundos (por ejemplo, 30 minutos (1800))
    $inactivity_time = 1800; 

    // Verifica si existe una sesión y si ha pasado el tiempo de inactividad
    if (isset($_SESSION['last_activity']) && (time() - $_SESSION['last_activity'] > $inactivity_time)) {
        // Si el usuario ha estado inactivo durante más tiempo que el tiempo de inactividad permitido, destruye la sesión y redirige al usuario a la página de inicio de sesión
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: inicio_sesion.php');
        exit();
    }

    // Actualiza el tiempo de actividad
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente no funciona porque tienes la comprobación de la duración de la sesión en un `elseif` con otras comparaciones que no tienen nada que ver con este tiempo.

Hay varias formas de resolverlo, una podría ser colocando la validación del tiempo de sesión al principio de cada archivo:

```php
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['time'])) {
    if(time() - $_SESSION['time'] > 30) { // Tiempo expirado
        header('location: ./cerrar_sesion.php'); exit;
    } else { // Interacción del usuario antes de que expire el tiempo
        $_SESSION['time'] = time(); // Actualiza la variable
    }
} // else - La sesion no está iniciada

// ... resto del código
```

Y en vez de copiarlo en todos los archivos, podrías colocar ese código en un archivo que sea requerido por todos, por ejemplo en el `header.php` donde esta el encabezado html, el menú superior (si lo hay) y otras cosas comunes en todas las páginas.

Comment: Lo he puesto al comienzo del index de uno de los tipos de usuarios he igual, no hace nada, y lo mismo en el código para el inicio de sesión, al comienzo antes de hacer la conexión con la base de datos pero igual, no me da error, pero tampoco soluciona.

Comment: @NovatoEnEsto si esto no soluciona tu problema, porque marcaste la respuesta como aceptada?

Comment: No se como funciona este foro, perdona, juraría que yo no le he dado a nada

Comment: @NovatoEnEsto observé que hay una tilde en `header('location: ./cerrar_sesion.php');` prueba sin la tilde. Obviamente el nombre del archivo físico tampoco debe tener la tilde. Verifica también que la sesión verdaderamente esté iniciada y que esté seteada la variable `$_SESSION['time']`.

Answer (score 0):

En algun momento tienes que destruir la sesión:

```
elseif ((time() - $_SESSION['time']) > 30)
        {
            header('location: ./cerrar_sesión.php');
        }
```

el cerrar_sesion.php debe tener algo asi:

```
if (!empty(['usuario']){
session_destroy();
Header('Location: Index.php');
} else {
Header ('Location:'.$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER];.');
}
```

y sacar la comprobacion de tiempo del else If ya que no tiene nada que ver con las otras comprobaciones que haces